# How do I make my BIND DNS Server public?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a BIND Server running a VM with bridged networking. I have a allowed it through the firewall with: `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=53/udp` and added a port forwarding configuration to my router:

[image]
[image]

I am running CentOS 8. My main goal is to that the DNS server reachable from outside the network and if you were on a different DNS server like Google's Public DNS. Here are my configuration files:

`named.conf`:

```
//
// named.conf
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only name server (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
//

options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.20; };
//      listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.1.0/24 };
        recursion yes;


        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;


        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";


        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "jpac14.io" IN {
        type master;
        file "jpac14.io.zone";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

`Zone Config: jpac14.io.zone`:

```
$TTL 1D
@   IN SOA  epc.jpac14.io.   root.epc.jpac14.io. (
                                       2020032001      ; serial
                                       1D              ; refresh
                                       1H              ; retry
                                       1W              ; expire
                                       3H )            ; minimum

$ORIGIN         jpac14.io.
jpac14.io.              IN      NS      epc.jpac14.io.
epc                     IN      A       127.0.0.1
beastpanel              IN      A       51.81.24.156
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but DNS is interesting in it uses both UDP and TCP port 53, so you will want to unblock that as well.  You may have an issue that your router is providing DNS and thus not forwarding the packets as desired.

Comment: @davidgo I'll try enable it on both UDP and TCP now, and when mean my router is providing the DNS, do you think I should change the default DNS to my local DNS server or. Also I will try set this up on a VPS with a dedicated IP.

Comment: I don't think changing the DNS on your local DNS server will make a difference. I'm implying your router firmware is probably buggy.

Comment: @davidgo I have allowed both TCP and UDP, still on a tool the checks if a port is open return that is not. I will try forwarding another application like SSH to see if it is a problem with BIND or the firewall

Comment: Yep, when I open the SSH port up it seems to work. This has to be a problem with my router. @davidgo

Comment: When I try to add a new configuration, when there is already a default it returns this https://i.imgur.com/zuAhe91.png I think this may work on a average home network like this. I will now try a VPS with a dedicated IP. @davidgo

Comment: One thing I notice is that your "allow-query" option in named.conf only has localhost, and your local network. ``allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.1.0/24 };``. If you are on the internet you definitely won't be coming from those. Have you tried opening that up?

Comment: @Gordster What do you suggest adding, my public IP? Also even when I open the port on my router it says it closed with online tools, so I think it may be my router.

Comment: This is interesting when I have my nslookup set to the DNS server it doesn't work. https://i.imgur.com/DHSR6r0.png But when I run it on the server it does work.

Comment: ``allow-query { any; }``   restart the service after you make the change

Comment: @Gordster Still not open, try do `vineyard.dyndns.biz` and port 53 its not open

Comment: try an external port other than the ones that are blocked. Does that work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105758/discussion-between-jpac14-and-gordster).

Comment: DLV is deprecated, do not use it anymore. (unrelated to your problem, but no need to clutter configuration with irrelevant obsolete stuff)

Comment: Show `dig` results querying your nameserver for both inside and outside of your network. Look at your bind logfiles too, and do network sniffing to double check if DNS packets flow as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is true, but if you want to add domains to the web you need to have a ICANN licence. You can make a public DNS server but only people using that DNS server will be able to access thoses records. If you would like other DNS servers (eg. Google's Public DNS) to get your DNS server records, you need to sign up for a ICANN licence which is a lot of money to get a licence. I don't know if this is entirely true but would love to hear your feedback. You can make a DNS server but it would only be a caching server it wouldn't append new domains to the internet like Google's Public DNS without buying a ICANN licence. I think I will not make a DNS server but only internal matter and I am best to buy a Namecheap domain.